# Pitest WARNING : Slave exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, pitest

How should i get rid of this warning and add the timeout constant for pitest?

My command is:

```
mvn jacoco:report org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage sonar:sonar -Dpitest.timeoutConst=8000
```

But it throws: WARNING : Slave exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT

Comment: There is nothing to worry about, can you verify the generated report : if the mutations marked as timed out don't look like infinite loops to you try a larger value for the timeout const, but this may slow down the process by causing a longer wait each time an infinite loop is encountered.

Comment: Already checked this comment - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pitusers/RFKOYSLmQ6o

Answer (score 13):

It is unlikely that you will be able to get rid of all the warnings - they are generated when a mutation creates an infinite loop.

Pitest detects these by comparing the execution time of each test with the time it took when no mutation is present. If the test takes significantly more time to run then the process is killed and the mutation marked as timed out.

The reason pitest reports a warning is in case it is being too hasty in marking a mutation as an infnite loop - it might be that things are running a bit slowly for other reasons.

If you have a lot of timeouts the first thing to do is examine the report and see if they all look like legitimate infinite loops. If they do then there is nothing more to be done.

Iff some of the timeouts do not look like infinite loops then you can try increasing the timeout constant.

This can be set in the pom, or passed on the commandline. It should not be prefixed with pitest.

`mvn org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage -DtimeoutConstant=8000`

Comment: I'm not sure if this was changed or a typo in the original answer, but with a more recent version of the pitest plugin (1.2.3), you need a slightly different spelling of the paramter. You'll need to use -DtimeoutConstant=8000 now

Comment: @Evert I believe you are correct.  I am using 1.4.3 and changing from timeoutConst to timeoutConstant worked for me

Comment: @henry How can I find those timed-out tests? Clicking them all in the report one by one?

Comment: -DtimeoutFactor=1.5 also an option, where the default value is 1.25

Comment: Sometimes, it's normal to encounter a timeout. I stumbled upon a recursive function code some time ago, where a mutation was causing an infinite loop.

Instead of increasing the timeout, the team refactored the function, and the timeout issue was resolved.